# Have Democrats attacked Trump's proposed wall as "medieval"?

Tags: united-states, politics

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQKrfGCd7I8) President Trump says "They say a wall is medieval, well so is a wheel".

The [official transcript](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/remarks-president-trump-roundtable-border-security-mcallen-tx/) says:

> **Democrat**s have refused to listen to the border agents, and they say this is a manufactured crisis.  That’s a new sound bite.  All over, I turn the television.  You know, I call it the opposition party.  It’s called the fake-news media.  And what happens is, every network has: “Manufactured Crisis.  “This is a man-…”  Every one of them.  It’s like they send out to everybody, “Let’s use this soundbite today.”  So it’s a manufa- — but it’s not.
>
> What is manufactured is the use of the word “manufactured.”  It’s manufactured by them, every single of the negatives.  But they’re not winning, because it’s common sense.  It’s common sense.  **They say a wall is medieval**.

However, is he merely tilting at a [straw man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man)? Have plural Democrats attacked the proposed border wall on the grounds that it is "medieval"?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

According to [Politico](https://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2019/01/02/democrats-mexico-broder-wall-223648):

> Chuck Schumer calls the wall “medieval.”

and according to [The Hill](https://thehill.com/blogs/floor-action/senate/422290-schumer-temper-tantrum-wont-give-gop-border-wall), Schumer said:

> Let me just walk my friends in the House through it. Democrats are not budging on the wall. We favor smart, effective border security, not a medieval wall. A Trump shut down will not convince a single Democrat to support bilking the American taxpayer for an ineffective, unnecessary and exorbitantly expensive wall.

Representative Hakeem Jeffries [tweeted](https://twitter.com/RepJeffries/status/1082822559920517120):

> We are not paying a $5 billion ransom note for your medieval  border wall.

California Attorney General Xavier Becerra [said](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/09/27/us/border-wall-california.html):

> If you take Trump at his word, he’s talking about some big medieval structure — a wall is a wall is a wall ... We’re now in the 21st century and realize that there are all kinds of barriers that combine to give true border security, which is something all of us want. But we’ve jumped beyond medieval walls.